# Database + Sync (Iphone app)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

How can I flush my sqlite database in my application when I click on a button?
I already have a database inside my app, when I click on a button it add some data into it.
I wanna know how to fluch the database after I click the button or maybe restart the application automatically.

Thanks,

Comment: Hi. What exactly do you mean by flush?

Comment: I want to restart it, becaue when I add new entry it not appear, I need to restart the application to see the new entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I find what I was looking for.
Don't really need to flush the database, the only things I had to do is to copy my database from the bundle to the document directory, because the database in the bundle is Read only.
Make a Copy of it allow to Write/Read access.

Add/Delete/Update data can be executed without problem after that.